# Counting $5$-character long Passwords with a Fixed Starting and Ending Points

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinatorics-on-words

Students are required to create $5$-character long passwords to access the library. The characters must be from lowercase letters or digits. Each password must start with a lowercase letter and end with a digit and contain at most $2$ digits. How many valid passwords are there? 
Is this solution correct?
$(26×(26^3) ×10) + (26×(26^2×10)×10)$

Comment: That is not right.  How many have the extra digit in the second spot, or the third spot, or the fourth spot? They are all different.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the mistake brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is not correct.  As noted in the comments, you have not accounted for the fact that the extra digit can go in one of three different slots.  Given the constraints, there are $26^4 \times 10$ passwords with exactly one digit, and there are $3 \times 26^3 \times 100$ passwords with exactly two digits, so the answer is the sum of those two numbers, $26^3 \times 560$.

Comment: Ohh, alright I get it now, Thank you so much! I totally forgot about them being at different positions in the 3 slots. Basically, I was confused about how to do it, but now it's pretty clear. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2):

26 possibilities for the first character 
10 possibilities for the last character (a digit)

2 cases:
there is a 2nd digit or there isn't.

case 1 : there is a 2nd digit
digit can go in any of 3 spots. 
$T_1 = 3 \times 10 \times 26^2.$

case 2 : there is no 2nd digit 
$T_2 = 26^3.$

Final answer:

$$26 \times 10 \times [T_1 + T_2].$$

Comment: Thank you so much brother, both of the above answers have cleared the concept. Next time, I'll look closely for the positions too. Thank you again mate!!!